# if I allow partner sites to republish my RSS feed, will that boost my SEO ranking?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, seo, feed, jsonp

I have a site. Would it help its SEO ranking if I allow B2B business customers to repost the site's blog's RSS feed (I'm thinking of using the partial RSS feed with links back to the site to "read more."), will that boost SEO rankings?

What if I (1) give the business customers (They may not be very tech savvy, and therefore, I'd like to give them the easiest solution.) JavaScript to put on their page that renders the RSS feed? Will the search engines even be able to detect this since it's done with JavaScript Or, (2) should I give them iFrame code? Or, (3) is the best option to write the server-side code (say PHP, Python, Ruby, ASP, JSP, etc.) necessary to serve the RSS feed?

(4) Should I worry about this approach hurting my SEO rankings because of all the duplicate content on different pages?

UPDATE:
I would like to go the javascript route that egrunin has suggested below. I had trouble getting the RSS content using javascript because most browsers prevent cross domain ajax. I do not want to force others to write server-side code to request the RSS content. I checked out how twitter does its badges but had trouble understanding it. I think I want to do something like this: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/12/21/json-dynamic-script-tag.html but currently I am using wordpress' out-of-the-box RSS feeds. It's not JSON. I guess I could write a php script that outputs it in JSON. Or, maybe the javascript can parse the XML to JSON. What do you think is the best approach?

Please advise.

UPDATE: I figured it out. See the answer I give below.

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: "Should I worry about this approach hurting my SEO rankings because of all the duplicate content on different pages?"  No.  Duplicate content on other people's sites can't be counted against you.  Otherwise competitors could maliciously duplicate your content.  You'll find that a lot of SEO books recommend RSS syndication as a method of building traffic and pagerank.

Comment: Good point. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this using a technique called JSONP (JSON with padding).

http://www.custudentloans.org/javascripts/cusl-page.js

Answer (score 1):

1. Search engines will never see the javascript implementation.  I like this option because you need not worry about anything much.
2. iframes are no good.
3. Serverside is a good option, though it requires the most work.
4. RSS is a pretty standard web format.  Syndication happens all the time.  The big search engines are smart enough to point to the original source.
5. It's not going to help you THAT much in SEO ***if at all***.  But it could bring new traffic by reaching a broader audience.
6. This isn't really a programming related question.

Comment: thanks! How do you know that "Search engines will never see the javascript implementation"? egrunin says they will. And why do you like that? If that's the case, the SEO will not be improved at all, correct? Why are iframes no good?

Comment: You shouldn't do this for SEO purposes.  RSS is for reaching more of an audience.  egrunin is actually right, if done his way the link will go back to your site.  You could even do something with noscript tags like `weather.com` widgets.  This is how `addthis` got so popular.  iFrames are a usability nightmare.

Comment: So my final advice?  Do it with Javascript to get more readers (or customers), but focus on other areas to improve your SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about the pagerank algorithm yes any links to your site from another site are helpful. Meaning if you have links from your client's site to yours it will boost your pagerank.

In terms of what crawlers can see they generally don't fully render JavaScript or iframed content so you should make it a server-side script.

Duplicate content isn't great on the web generally because if they have a better rank then you they might actually appear before you but generally it should be okay especially if they are only posting title/description.

Comment: Things aren't so black and white anymore.  Just having a better pagerank will not gaurantee a better SERP placement.

Comment: @Stephen you are correct especially considering sites have so much user generated content but a better pagerank really can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

You should give them a simple script tag to paste onto their page, like this:

```
<script src="MattDiPasquale.com/theScript.aspx"></script>
```

And then emit whatever javascript you want. That javascript will write out your content.

If your content is links to your pages, yes, it will increase your PageRank. The old rule that search engines ignore javascript-generated content is no longer true.

You emit RSS links instead if you want. That's the beauty of this approach, you have complete control. Also you know which sites are getting how much traffic, which often turns out to be useful.

One downside is that a massive site will put stress on your server. Also, a bug in your code will affect everyone using it, so there's a little extra pressure there.

Comment: Thanks, engrunin. How do you know that search engines, e.g, Google bot, will execute the JavaScript code?

Comment: Because I've seen what they do with my sites. (Can't tell you more than that, I'm afraid, but I think you'll find confirmation if you look around.)

Comment: I'm working on the script now. Do you have an example of how to code it?

Comment: I'm going by how Twitter & Facebook do their badges.