# Debugging HTML & JavaScript with Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, firebug, jsonp

I made a [JSONP widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764152/if-i-allow-partner-sites-to-republish-my-rss-feed-will-that-boost-my-seo-ranking/3946968#3946968).

However, when one of the partner sites put it in [their page](http://njcul.org/college-resource-center.aspx), (1) it doesn't render at all in IE and (2) in other browsers (Firefox & Google Chrome), the HTML of the widget renders incorrectly: the `<aside>` closes prematurely, before the Financial Aid Glossary. It's something specific to that page because it works fine on this [example college resource center page](http://www.acani.com/custudentloans-feed-example).

To fix these two issues, I tried saving the page source to a local file and messing around with the local file and with Firebug, deleting DOM elements and stuff. I even tried fixing the errors that [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnjcul.org%2Fcollege-resource-center.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) found. But, I still couldn't get it to render correctly.

How should I tell them to change their page so that the widget renders correctly? Or, how should I update the [widget script](http://www.custudentloans.org/javascripts/cusl-page.js) I wrote?

They may take their page down since it's not rendering correctly, so here's the source of the page just in case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="ctl01_Head1" profile="New Jersey Credit Union League"><title>
 College Resource Center - New Jersey Credit Union League
</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/csshandler.ashx?skin=InnerTemplate&amp;s=1&amp;v=2.3.5.8' />
<!--[if IE]>
<script defer="defer" src="http://njcul.org/ClientScript/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://njcul.org/Data/Sites/1/skins/InnerTemplate/IESpecific.css?cb=9d546eec-6752-4067-8f94-9a5b642213e4" type="text/css" id="IE6CSS" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://njcul.org/Data/Sites/1/skins/InnerTemplate/IE7Specific.css?cb=9d546eec-6752-4067-8f94-9a5b642213e4" type="text/css" id="IE7CSS" />
<![endif]-->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="New Jersey Credit Union League" href="http://njcul.org/SearchEngineInfo.ashx" />
 <!--[if IE]>
 <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)" /><meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)" />
 <![endif]-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=670, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-scale=0.45" />

<link rel='shortcut icon' href='http://njcul.org/Data/Sites/1/skins/InnerTemplate/favicon.ico' />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
    var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
  }
  function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
    var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
   var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
   if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
  }

  function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
    var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
   d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
    if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
    for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
    if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
  }

  function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
    var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
     if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
  }
  //-->
 </script>
<link href="App_Themes/pageskin/theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://njcul.org/college-resource-center.aspx' /><style type="text/css">
 .ctl01_SiteMenu1_ctl00_0 { background-color:white;visibility:hidden;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }
 .ctl01_SiteMenu1_ctl00_1 { text-decoration:none; }
 .ctl01_SiteMenu1_ctl00_2 {  }
 .ctl01_PageMenu1_ctl01_0 { background-color:white;visibility:hidden;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }
 .ctl01_PageMenu1_ctl01_1 { text-decoration:none; }
 .ctl01_PageMenu1_ctl01_2 {  }
 .ctl01_PageMenu2_ctl01_0 { text-decoration:none; }

</style></head>
<body class="pagebody" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('ps_menu_down.png')">
<form method="post" action="/college-resource-center.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="ctl01_ScriptManager1_HiddenField" id="ctl01_ScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" id="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" value="45" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMjA1OTAyNzk1MQ9kFgJmD2QWBAIBDxYCHgdwcm9maWxlBR5OZXcgSmVyc2V5IENyZWRpdCBVbmlvbiBMZWFndWVkAgMP" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE1" id="__VIEWSTATE1" value="ZBYiAgEPFgIeD1NpdGVNYXBQcm92aWRlcgUJbW9qb3NpdGUxZAIDDxYEHwEFCW1vam9zaXRlMR4PU3RhcnRpbmdOb2RlVXJsBQt+" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE2" id="__VIEWSTATE2" value="L2hvbWUuYXNweGQCBQ8WBB8BBQltb2pvc2l0ZTEfAgUYfi9lZHVjYXRpb24tLWV2ZW50cy5hc3B4ZAIHDxYCHwEFCW1vam9zaXRl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE3" id="__VIEWSTATE3" value="MWQCFQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCGw9kFgJmDw8WAh8DaGQWBgIBDxYCHwNoFgJmDw8WAh4EVGV4dAULU2l0ZSBTZWFyY2hkZAID" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE4" id="__VIEWSTATE4" value="Dw8WAh8DaGRkAgUPDxYCHwNoZGQCIQ8PFgIfA2hkZAInD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DaGRkAi0PZBYGAgEPDxYCHghJbWFnZVVybAUrL0Rh" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE5" id="__VIEWSTATE5" value="dGEvU2l0ZXMvMS9za2lucy9Jbm5lclRlbXBsYXRlL2hlYWQxLmpwZ2RkAgMPDxYCHwUFKy9EYXRhL1NpdGVzLzEvc2tpbnMvSW5u" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE6" id="__VIEWSTATE6" value="ZXJUZW1wbGF0ZS9oZWFkMi5qcGdkZAIFDw8WAh8FBSsvRGF0YS9TaXRlcy8xL3NraW5zL0lubmVyVGVtcGxhdGUvaGVhZDMuanBn" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE7" id="__VIEWSTATE7" value="ZGQCLw9kFgRmDw8WAh8DaGRkAgQPDxYCHwNoZGQCMQ8PFgQeCENzc0NsYXNzBTlhcnQtbGF5b3V0LWNlbGwgYXJ0LXNpZGViYXIx" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE8" id="__VIEWSTATE8" value="IGxlZnRzaWRlIGxlZnQyY29sdW1uIGNtc3pvbmUeBF8hU0ICAmQWBAIBD2QWAgICD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPZBYCZhA8KwAJAgAPFhIe" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE9" id="__VIEWSTATE9" value="FENvbGxhcHNlSW1hZ2VUb29sVGlwBRNDb2xsYXBzZSB0aGlzIG5vZGUuHg1QYXRoU2VwYXJhdG9yBHweC0V4cGFuZERlcHRoZh4S" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE10" id="__VIEWSTATE10" value="RXhwYW5kSW1hZ2VUb29sVGlwBRFFeHBhbmQgdGhpcyBub2RlLh4SU2hvd0V4cGFuZENvbGxhcHNlZx4NTmV2ZXJFeHBhbmRlZGQe" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE11" id="__VIEWSTATE11" value="C18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZx4XUG9wdWxhdGVOb2Rlc0Zyb21DbGllbnRnHgxEYXRhU291cmNlSUQFEGxldmVsM2RhdGFzb3VyY2VkCBQr" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE12" id="__VIEWSTATE12" value="AAsFPzA6MCwwOjEsMDoyLDA6MywwOjQsMDo1LDA6NiwwOjcsMTo3LDA6NywwOjgsMTo4LDA6OCwxOjgsMDo4LDA6ORQrAAIWDB8E" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE13" id="__VIEWSTATE13" value="BRJDYWxlbmRhciBvZiBFdmVudHMeBVZhbHVlBSQyMmU3NmVlZC1iZWM0LTRjNWItYWJhNC04MTVjNTJmNTJiNDQeC05hdmlnYXRl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE14" id="__VIEWSTATE14" value="VXJsBRl+L2NhbGVuZGFyLW9mLWV2ZW50cy5hc3B4HghEYXRhUGF0aAUCNjceCURhdGFCb3VuZGceEFBvcHVsYXRlT25EZW1hbmRo" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE15" id="__VIEWSTATE15" value="ZBQrAAIWDB8EBRBDaGFwdGVyIE1lZXRpbmdzHxEFJGNiZGUyMTFhLTc0YzItNDI2Zi05NjQ4LTQ5NTY2ZjY4NjViNx8SBRd+L2No" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE16" id="__VIEWSTATE16" value="YXB0ZXItbWVldGluZ3MuYXNweB8TBQI2OB8UZx8VaGQUKwACFgwfBAUOU3BlY2lhbCBFdmVudHMfEQUkODgxZjE0Y2EtMWI0NC00" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE17" id="__VIEWSTATE17" value="YjYxLWE2YmQtMjk2Mzc0NzMyZGY1HxIFFX4vc3BlY2lhbC1ldmVudHMuYXNweB8TBQI2OR8UZx8VZ2QUKwACFgwfBAUURWR1Y2F0" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE18" id="__VIEWSTATE18" value="aW9uYWwgU2Vzc2lvbnMfEQUkM2QxYTBmZWUtMTk1Ny00MGYwLThlMzItNzEzMjM4ZDM5Yjg5HxIFG34vZWR1Y2F0aW9uYWwtc2Vz" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE19" id="__VIEWSTATE19" value="c2lvbnMuYXNweB8TBQI3MB8UZx8VZ2QUKwACFgwfBAUsU3BlY2lhbCBDVSBEaXJlY3RvciAmYW1wOyBWb2x1bnRlZXIgUHJvZ3Jh" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE20" id="__VIEWSTATE20" value="bXMfEQUkMGRjNWUwY2EtMWQyNy00N2JlLTgwMjgtNmYzY2Q2NmNjNTkzHxIFLX4vc3BlY2lhbC1jdS1kaXJlY3Rvci12b2x1bnRl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE21" id="__VIEWSTATE21" value="ZXItcHJvZ3JhbXMuYXNweB8TBQMxNjgfFGcfFWhkFCsAAhYMHwQFG0NVTkEgTGVhcm5pbmcgT3Bwb3J0dW5pdGllcx8RBSQyZTRl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE22" id="__VIEWSTATE22" value="YWYyMS0wNjEwLTQ5OWYtYTVmMy1lN2VlNjM2ZWZiMmUfEgUifi9jdW5hLWxlYXJuaW5nLW9wcG9ydHVuaXRpZXMuYXNweB8TBQI2" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE23" id="__VIEWSTATE23" value="Nh8UZx8VaGQUKwACFgwfBAUrWW91dGggSW52b2x2ZW1lbnQgQm9hcmQgU2Nob2xhcnNoaXAgUHJvZ3JhbR8RBSRjNjUzMjQwNC1k" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE24" id="__VIEWSTATE24" value="OTY1LTQ4ZmYtYTZhNC02YmFkYjU4ZDE0YTAfEgUKfi95aWIuYXNweB8TBQI5Nh8UZx8VaGQUKwACFgwfBAUbRXhlY3V0aXZlIExl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE25" id="__VIEWSTATE25" value="YWRlcnNoaXAgU2VyaWVzHxEFJDE0MTg2ZTUzLWI4MWMtNDIzOS1iMDM5LWY5N2U2ZTI2ZDU4OR8SBQp+L2Vscy5hc3B4HxMFAzEy" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE26" id="__VIEWSTATE26" value="OR8UZx8VaGQUKwACFgwfBAUUQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUgUHJvZ3JhbXMfEQUkNjMxYWFkMzctY2NhZS00OTFhLWE3YjAtODI3NzM5YWM1" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE27" id="__VIEWSTATE27" value="NjZhHxIFGn4vY2VydGlmaWNhdGVwcm9ncmFtcy5hc3B4HxMFAzE1Mx8UZx8VZ2QUKwACFhAfBAUXQ29sbGVnZSBSZXNvdXJjZSBD" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE28" id="__VIEWSTATE28" value="ZW50ZXIfEQUkOTI3NDJkM2QtZTYzYS00OTg2LTgwMTYtYjNkNjlhNWU5NzA3HxIFHn4vY29sbGVnZS1yZXNvdXJjZS1jZW50ZXIu" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE29" id="__VIEWSTATE29" value="YXNweB8TBQMxNjYfFGceCFNlbGVjdGVkZx8VaB4IRXhwYW5kZWRnZAUPY3RsMDEkY3RsMDZ8bm5uZAIDDw8WAh8DaGRkAjMPDxYE" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE30" id="__VIEWSTATE30" value="HwYFNWFydC1sYXlvdXQtY2VsbCBhcnQtY29udGVudCBjZW50ZXItbGVmdG1hcmdpbiBjbXN6b25lHwcCAmQWBgIBD2QWAmYPDxYE" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE31" id="__VIEWSTATE31" value="HwYFC2JyZWFkY3J1bWJzHwcCAmQWAgIBDzwrAAUBAA8WBh4VUGFyZW50TGV2ZWxzRGlzcGxheWVkAgIfCQUDID4gHwNnZBYGZg9k" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE32" id="__VIEWSTATE32" value="FgICAQ8PFggfEgUKL2hvbWUuYXNweB8EBQRIb21lHwYFD3Vuc2VsZWN0ZWRjcnVtYh8HAgJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WCB8SBRcvZWR1" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE33" id="__VIEWSTATE33" value="Y2F0aW9uLS1ldmVudHMuYXNweB8EBRZFZHVjYXRpb24gJmFtcDsgRXZlbnRzHwYFD3Vuc2VsZWN0ZWRjcnVtYh8HAgJkZAIED2QW" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE34" id="__VIEWSTATE34" value="AgIBDw8WCB8SBR0vY29sbGVnZS1yZXNvdXJjZS1jZW50ZXIuYXNweB8EBRdDb2xsZWdlIFJlc291cmNlIENlbnRlch8GBQ1zZWxl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE35" id="__VIEWSTATE35" value="Y3RlZGNydW1iHwcCAmRkAgMPDxYCHwNoZGQCBQ9kFgJmD2QWAmYPDxYEHwYFCW1vZHVsZTI0MR8HAgJkFgICAQ9kFgICAw9kFgIC" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE36" id="__VIEWSTATE36" value="Aw9kFgICAQ8PFgQeC0NvbnRlbnRHdWlkKClYU3lzdGVtLkd1aWQsIG1zY29ybGliLCBWZXJzaW9uPTIuMC4wLjAsIEN1bHR1cmU9" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE37" id="__VIEWSTATE37" value="bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49Yjc3YTVjNTYxOTM0ZTA4OSRmOWU3YTZiYy1lYjYzLTQ0YzQtOGQyYS1hYTEyMmZmMTJh" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE38" id="__VIEWSTATE38" value="YTMfA2hkFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWBAIFD2QWAmYPFgIeCkNhbGxiYWNrSUQFKWN0bDAxJG1haW5Db250ZW50JGN0bDAwJFJhdGluZyRV" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE39" id="__VIEWSTATE39" value="c2VyUmF0aW5nZAIHDxYCHxEFJGY5ZTdhNmJjLWViNjMtNDRjNC04ZDJhLWFhMTIyZmYxMmFhM2QCNQ8PFgYfBgURcmlnaHRzaWRl" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE40" id="__VIEWSTATE40" value="IGNtc3pvbmUfBwICHwNoZGQCNw8PFgQfBgUTYWx0Y29udGVudDIgY21zem9uZR8HAgJkZAI5Dw8WBB8GBRNhbHRjb250ZW50MiBj" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE41" id="__VIEWSTATE41" value="bXN6b25lHwcCAmRkAj0PDxYCHwNoZBYKAgEPDxYCHwNoZGQCAw8PFgIfA2hkZAIFDw8WAh8DaGRkAgcPDxYCHwNoZGQCCQ8PFgIf" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE42" id="__VIEWSTATE42" value="A2hkZAJBDw8WAh8DaGRkGAMFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBRVjdGwwMSRQYWdlTWVudTIkY3RsMDEF" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE43" id="__VIEWSTATE43" value="FWN0bDAxJFBhZ2VNZW51MSRjdGwwMQ8PZAUkY2E4YTRkMmQtYWZkMy00ZGQ2LWIxYzEtYWY0MjhiOTc4ZThjZAUVY3RsMDEkU2l0" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE44" id="__VIEWSTATE44" value="ZU1lbnUxJGN0bDAwDw9kBSQ2ZWU5NzFjZC05OTU2LTRkYzMtODE2Mi1hNDg4NDEzZTdmNThk" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=x2eneDuLFQ9w4yRoi8Y5tg2&amp;t=634230536572508135" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script  type="text/javascript">var GB_ROOT_DIR = '/ClientScript/greybox/'; var GBCloseText = 'Close'; </script>
<script  src="/ClientScript/mojocombined/mojocombinedfull.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script  src="/ClientScript/jqmojo/cycle.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=wCo0V0P8aplVAKjdc-kM9AvNmwrQFDA24wrkA7OkI6gOYp_VxxHWIc8VlP8L0l200&amp;t=fffffffff615adfd" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Services._AuthenticationService.DefaultWebServicePath = 'Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd';
Sys.Services._RoleService.DefaultWebServicePath = 'Role_JSON_AppService.axd';
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=wCo0V0P8aplVAKjdc-kM9AvNmwrQFDA24wrkA7OkI6gjdZ5z-Kq5dVZ7FGYv9jU40&amp;t=fffffffff615adfd" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
document.getElementById('ctl01_ctl06').value = GetViewState__AspNetTreeView('ctl01_PageMenu2_ctl01_UL');
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>






<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl01$ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls(['tctl01$PageMenu1$upMenu','tctl01$PageMenu2$upMenu'], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>

<div id="wrapwebsite">
<img src="top.png" border="0" width="900" height="36">
    <div class="topnav">
  <ul>


   <li class="firstnav"><a class="sitelink homelink" href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li class="topnavitem"><a class="sitelink" href="/SiteMap.aspx">Site Map</a></li>




   <li class='topnavitem'><a href='/SearchResults.aspx' class='sitelink'>Search</a></li>

   <li class="topnavitem"><a class="sitelink" href="/Secure/Login.aspx">Sign In</a></li>

    </ul>  
        <a href='#startcontent' class='skiplink'>Skip over navigation</a>
      <div id="ctl01_pnlStandardLogin" class="floatpanel">



</div>
        <div class="addthis">
        <div id="ctl01_InsecurePanel1" class="addthisbutton">



</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="topmenu">


<div class="AspNet-Menu-Horizontal" id="ctl01_SiteMenu1_ctl00">
  <ul class="AspNet-Menu">

   <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf AspNet-Menu-SelectedLeaf">
    <a href="/home.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu AspNet-Menu-SelectedLeaf">
     <img src="Data/SiteImages/FeatureIcons/house.png" alt="Home" /> Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
    <a href="/professional-products-and-services.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
     Professional Products and Services</a>

   </li>
   <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
    <a href="/news-publications-announcements.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
     News, Publications &amp; Announcements</a>
   </li>
  </ul>

</div>


    </div> 
    <div id="wrapheader">
       <a href="/default.aspx"><img src="logo.png" border="0" width="420" height="104" align="left"></a>
   <a href="Secure/Login.aspx" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('memberLogin','','ps_menu_down2.png',1)"><img src="ps_menu_up2.png" alt="Member Login" name="memberLogin" width="171" height="20" border="0" style="padding-left:270px; padding-top:0px;"></a><br />
   <!--<a href="products-and-services.aspx" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('productsServices','','ps_menu_down.png',1)"><img src="ps_menu_up.png" alt="Access Products & Services" name="productsServices" width="171" height="20" border="0" style="padding-left:95px;"></a>-->  
      <a href="professional-products-and-services.aspx"><img src="productServicesNav.jpg" border="0" width="203" height="37" style="padding-left:200px; padding-top:54px;"></a>

     <!--
   <h1 class='art-Logo-name art-logo-name siteheading'><a class='siteheading' href='http://njcul.org/Default.aspx'>New Jersey Credit Union League</a></h1>  
   <div id="ctl01_spanel1" class="rotatecontainer">

   <img id="ctl01_imgs1" class="rotateitem" src="/Data/Sites/1/skins/InnerTemplate/head1.jpg" alt=" " style="border-width:0px;" />
   <img id="ctl01_imgs2" class="rotateitem" src="/Data/Sites/1/skins/InnerTemplate/head2.jpg" alt=" " style="border-width:0px;" />
   <img id="ctl01_imgs3" class="rotateitem" src="/Data/Sites/1/skins/InnerTemplate/head3.jpg" alt=" " style="border-width:0px;" />

</div>
  -->
 </div>
 <div id="outercontainer"> 


<div id="ctl01_PageMenu1_upMenu">


 <div class="AspNet-Menu-Horizontal" id="ctl01_PageMenu1_ctl01">
   <ul class="AspNet-Menu">
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
     <a href="/consumer-advocacy.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
      Consumer Advocacy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
     <a href="/compliance.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">

      Compliance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf AspNet-Menu-SelectedLeaf">
     <a href="/education--events.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu AspNet-Menu-SelectedLeaf">
      Education &amp; Events</a>
    </li>
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">

     <a href="/government-affairs.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
      Government Affairs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
     <a href="/news.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
      News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">

     <a href="/about-us.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
      About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
     <a href="/nj-credit-union-foundation.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu">
      Foundation </a>
    </li>
   </ul>

 </div>

</div>


    <div id="innercontainer">
    <div id="wrapcenter">
     <div id="ctl01_divLeft" class="art-layout-cell art-sidebar1 leftside left2column cmszone">

 <div id="gutter">

<div id="ctl01_PageMenu2_upMenu">


  <div class="AspNet-TreeView" id="ctl01_PageMenu2_ctl01">

    <ul id="ctl01_PageMenu2_ctl01_UL">
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
      <a href="/calendar-of-events.aspx">
       Calendar of Events</a>
     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
      <a href="/chapter-meetings.aspx">
       Chapter Meetings</a>

     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root">
      <a class="AspNet-TreeView-Expand" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl01$PageMenu2$ctl01','p881f14ca-1b44-4b61-a6bd-296374732df5'); return false;" href="/special-events.aspx" title="Expand this node.">&nbsp;</a>
      <a href="/special-events.aspx">
       Special Events</a>
     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root">
      <a class="AspNet-TreeView-Expand" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl01$PageMenu2$ctl01','p3d1a0fee-1957-40f0-8e32-713238d39b89'); return false;" href="/educational-sessions.aspx" title="Expand this node.">&nbsp;</a>

      <a href="/educational-sessions.aspx">
       Educational Sessions</a>
     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
      <a href="/special-cu-director-volunteer-programs.aspx">
       Special CU Director &amp; Volunteer Programs</a>
     </li>

     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
      <a href="/cuna-learning-opportunities.aspx">
       CUNA Learning Opportunities</a>
     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
      <a href="/yib.aspx">
       Youth Involvement Board Scholarship Program</a>
     </li>

     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
      <a href="/els.aspx">
       Executive Leadership Series</a>
     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root">
      <a class="AspNet-TreeView-Expand" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl01$PageMenu2$ctl01','p631aad37-ccae-491a-a7b0-827739ac566a'); return false;" href="/certificateprograms.aspx" title="Expand this node.">&nbsp;</a>
      <a href="/certificateprograms.aspx">
       Certificate Programs</a>

     </li>
     <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Root AspNet-TreeView-Leaf AspNet-TreeView-Selected">
      <a href="/college-resource-center.aspx">
       College Resource Center</a>
     </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

 </div>


    </div>
      <!---->
      <a id="startcontent"></a>


</div>
     <div id="ctl01_divCenter" class="art-layout-cell art-content center-leftmargin cmszone">

            <div id="ctl01_Breadcrumbs_pnlWrapper" class="breadcrumbs">


<span id="ctl01_Breadcrumbs_breadCrumbsControl"><span>
<a id="ctl01_Breadcrumbs_breadCrumbsControl_ctl00_lnkNode" class="unselectedcrumb" href="/home.aspx">Home</a>
</span><span> > </span><span>
<a id="ctl01_Breadcrumbs_breadCrumbsControl_ctl02_lnkNode" class="unselectedcrumb" href="/education--events.aspx">Education &amp; Events</a>
</span><span> > </span><span>
<a id="ctl01_Breadcrumbs_breadCrumbsControl_ctl04_lnkCurrent" class="selectedcrumb" href="/college-resource-center.aspx">College Resource Center</a>
</span></span>

 </div>

         <div id="ctl01_mainContent_ctl00_pnlContainer" class="module241">



<div id="ctl01_mainContent_ctl00_pnlWrapper" class="art-Post-inner panelwrapper htmlmodule">

<a id='module241' class='moduleanchor'></a><h2 class="art-PostHeader moduletitle">CUStudentLoans.org College Resource Center <a class="ModuleEditLink"></a></h2>


<div class=" modulecontent">
<div id="ctl01_mainContent_ctl00_divContent" class="slidecontainer">
      <style>
    /* Edit the font family and width of overall content */
    #cusl-page { font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Lucida, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 62.5%; width: 630px; }
    /* Link colors */
    #cusl-page a { color: #004a80; }
    /* Header image */
    #cusl-page #header { display:none !important; }
    /* Heading text color */
    #cusl-content h2 { color: #0e6c55; font-size:18px; }
    #cusl-page aside h3 a { font-size:16px }
    #cusl-page aside h2 { font-size:18px; }
    #cusl-content article h3 a { font-size:20px; line-height:26px !important; }
  </style>

  <script src="https://www.custudentloans.org/javascripts/cusl-page.js"></script>
  <script>
    new CUSL.Page({
      count: 5, // defaults to 7
      cu_url: 'http://www.custudentloans.org'
    }).render();
  </script>
  <div id="footer">
    <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.custudentloans.org/student/college-financing-101">Learn more about Private Student Loans at <em>Ken's Korner</em></a></p>
  </div>
   </div>

</div>
<div class="modulefooter"></div>

<div class="cleared"></div>

  </div>



 </div>


</div>

 </div>

     <div id="ctl01_divAlt1" class="altcontent2 cmszone">



</div>
 <div id="ctl01_divAltContent2" class="altcontent2 cmszone">



</div>
<div id="wrapfooter">
  <img src="footerImage.png" border="0" width="900" height="134">    
     &copy; 2008 - 2011 New Jersey Credit Union League |
         <a href="/privacy-policy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a> | Design and Website by: <a href="http://www.greylockmarketing.com/" target="_blank">Greylock Marketing</a> & <a href="http://www.socialboostmedia.com/" target="_blank">Social Boost Media</a>

   <br /> <br />
 </div>
 </div> 
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideMenuToolbar(){ $("#toolbar").fadeOut(); $("#toolbarbut").fadeIn("slow");}
function ShowMenuToolbar(){ $("#toolbar").fadeIn(); $("#toolbarbut").fadeOut("slow");}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("span.downarr a").click(function() {HideMenuToolbar(); Set_Cookie('openstate', 'closed')});
  $("span.showbar a").click(function() {ShowMenuToolbar(); Set_Cookie('openstate', 'open') });
  $("span.downarr a, span.showbar a").click(function() { return false; }); 
 var openState = Get_Cookie('openstate');
 if(openState != null){ if(openState == 'closed'){HideMenuToolbar();} if(openState == 'open'){ShowMenuToolbar();}}
}); 
</script>



<div>
 <input type="hidden" name="ctl01$ctl06" id="ctl01_ctl06" />

</div>
<div>

 <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQKv1e3VCALs75XzDgL+qaz3AwLv26TNCQKS/MC2Dg==" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">Sys.Application.add_load(function() { var form = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._form; form._initialAction = form.action = window.location.href; }); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ctl01_ScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();
WebForm_InitCallback();//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" > $('div.mojo-accordion').accordion({fx:{opacity:'toggle',duration:'fast'}}); $('div.mojo-accordion-nh').accordion({fx:{opacity:'toggle',duration:'fast'},autoHeight:false});  $('div.mojo-tabs').tabs({fx:{opacity:'toggle',duration:'fast'}}); $('input.jqbutton').button(); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#ctl01_spanel1').cycle({fx:'fade',speed:1000,timeout:3000,next:'#ctl01_spanel1'});</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
try{
var mojoPageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-19333588-1");

mojoPageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "member-type", "anonymous", 1);mojoPageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {} </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're going to have to get more specific. thats a lot of code to read for a pretty vague question.

Comment: IE doens't like what you are setting in that innerHTML. There are a lot of other people running into this (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unknown+runtime+error+innerhtml). I would start by shrinking down the html you are writing to the page in the widget. Try to figure out what part of that HTML IE doesn't like.

Comment: One issue I'd have with the "widget" code you posted is its use of `document.write()`.  That's almost always a terrible idea.

Comment: @Hemlock, @Pointy, but, as explained in my question, this [example college resource center page](http://www.acani.com/custudentloans-feed-example) uses the same widget code and works fine in IE and all major browsers.

Comment: @greg, you don't have to read the code. Just figure out how to change it to make it render like this [example college resource center page](http://www.acani.com/custudentloans-feed-example). Start by saving the code to an html file and opening it in Firefox. Then, compare it to the example. You'll see that the <aside> is being closed prematurely, before the Financial Aid Glossary. I feel like I'm repeating myself... What other specifics would you like? If I knew specifically why this was happening, I'd have answered my own question.

Comment: user firebug lite to trace your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox doesn't like your form element for some reason.  It strips it out and then tries to correct an error, which results in the aside being closed too early as you've reported.

I had to go through and close **all** of your hr, br, img, and input tags so that I could rule out those as being bugs.  Afterwards, I started a process of elimination where I removed sections of this HTML until the content positioned itself correctly.  By a process of elimination, tearing everything down until the problem went away followed by slowly building it back up to the point where everything else is in place and rendering okay, I narrowed the problem to your **form** tag.

I can't see anything in the form tag that would indicate a problem, but judging by the amount of unclosed tags I found, I wouldn't be surprised if a series of **technical debt** issues are cascading bugs throughout the site.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/paying-down-your-technical-debt.html

Here you can see that I used HTML comments to comment out your form opening and close tag:

**cusl-page.js:**

```
      <!--<form action="' + finaid + 'calculators/scripts/loanpayments.cgi" method="POST">-->\
          <input type="hidden" name="calctype" value="loan_payments" />\
          <input type="hidden" value="tables" name="output_format" />\
          <dl>\
            <dt><label for="loan_balance">Loan Balance</label></dt>\
            <dd><input id="loan_balance" size="12" value="" name="loan_balance"/></dd>\
            <dt><label for="loan_interest_rate">Interest Rate</label></dt>\
            <dd><input id="loan_interest_rate" size="5" value="6.8%" name="loan_interest_rate"/></dd>\
            <dt><label for="loan_fees">Loan Fees</label></dt>\
            <dd><input id="loan_fees" size="5" value="0.0%" name="loan_fees"/></dd>\
            <dt><label for="loan_term_in_years">Loan Term (Years)</label></dt>\
            <dd><input id="loan_term_in_years" maxlength="5" size="2" value="10" name="loan_term_in_years"/></dd>\
            <dt><label for="minimum_payment">Minimum Payment</label></dt>\
            <dd><input id="minimum_payment" size="4" value="$50" name="minimum_payment"/></dd>\
            <dt><label for="enrollment_status">Enrollment Status</label></dt>\
            <dd><select id="enrollment_status" size="1" name="enrollment_status">\
              <option selected="" value="">Not Specified</option>\
              <option value="Still in School">Still in School</option>\
              <option value="Graduating Soon">Graduating Soon</option>\
              <option value="In Repayment">In Repayment</option></select></dd>\
            <dt><label for="degree_program">Degree Program</label></dt>\
            <dd><select id="degree_program" size="1" name="degree_program">\
              <option selected="" value="">Not Specified</option>\
              <option value="Associate\'s Degree">Associate\'s Degree</option>\
              <option value="Bachelor\'s Degree">Bachelor\'s Degree</option>\
              <option value="Master\'s Degree">Master\'s Degree</option>\
              <option value="Ph.D.">Ph.D.</option>\
              <option value="Lawyer (LLB or JD)">Lawyer (LLB or JD)</option>\
              <option value="Doctor (M.D.)">Doctor (M.D.)</option></select></dd>\
            <dt><label for="fte_enrollment">Total Years in College</label></dt>\
            <dd><input id="fte_enrollment" size="4" value="" name="fte_enrollment"/></dd>\
            <dt>Print payment schedule?</dt>\
            <dd>\
              <input id="yes" type="radio" value="yes" name="print_schedule"/>\
              <label for="yes">Yes</label>\
              <input id="no" type="radio" checked value="no" name="print_schedule"/>\
              <label for="no">No</label>\
            </dd>\
          </dl>\
          <button type="submit">Calculate</button>\
        <!--</form>--></div>\
```

Below is a screenshot of the page rendering correctly in Firefox 3.6 with the form tags commented.  Note this is on my local server, not the live site:

[image]

Understand that I've spent over two hours working on this, and we still haven't even touched Internet Explorer yet.  Knowing how IE is, it may take even longer to get this working for you.

Unfortunately, this code is so cluttered with a mixture of JavaScript and HTML that it will make this impossible to maintain.  I don't know if you inherited it from someone else or wrote it yourself, but it will eventually need to be rewritten or cleaned up somehow.

I know you are under a deadline and don't have time to rebuild this now, so I offer the following workaround:

- A workaround to meet your goal would be to use some other method to submit that form data, such as AJAX, and leave that form tag commented.

You could also go through your code and close any other br, hr, img, input, and any other tags that need to be self-closed, like in these examples below:

Self closing tags need to be explicitly closed:

```
   <!-- note the self-closing slashes on the ends -->
   <img src="/image.jpg" />
   <br />
   <input type="text" value="" />
```

Running this through a validator would be helpful as well to identify anything that may cause the browser's HTML parsers to be unable to properly parse the document.

No matter what, these types of problems involve commenting lines of HTML until the problem is narrowed to a certain block of code.  By having a more modular design that respects the rules of keeping your content (HTML), behavior (JavaScript), and presentation (CSS) completely separate, you eliminate the need to go on these wild goose chases as the problems will be easier to track down.

Good luck!  I hope this answer helps you solve this stubborn problem.

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thanks so much for your help. I noticed they've wrapped practically their whole page with `<form>`, but when I took them out, it didn't seem to fix the issue. But, you're saying I should take mine out... hmm... Well, one of the forms should probably go; I don't think form elements can be nested. I'll look into this tomorrow though. One side note, [HTML5 void elements no longer need self-closing slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693939/self-closing-tags-void-elements-in-html5). I know, it's difficult to swallow.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale - Didn't know about the new convention.  Thanks for pointing that out.  However, Firefox 3.6 isn't an HTML5 supported browser.  Do you think that matters?  Also, I forgot to mention in my answer that I imported headjs library to make the code forwards compatible with older browsers:  http://headjs.com/.  I also think you're right about that toplevel form.  You don't need that, and getting rid of that may solve many of your problems after all!

Comment: @jmort253 actually [Firefox does support HTML5](http://html5test.com/), just not all features yet. Although it doesn't support section elements, `<!DOCTYPE html>` does trigger Standards Mode, and the section elements render correctly in Firefox 3.6, so I don't think the section elements are causing the problem. I may try changing the section elements, like `<aside>`, to `<div>`s. [Head JS](http://headjs.com/) looks sweet. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale - My main focus is on WebSockets, so I guess I misjudged Firefox.  Thanks for pointing that out, and thanks for the HTML5 Test link.  It reminds me of the Acid Test: http://acid3.acidtests.org/

Comment: @jmort253, I had some more time to look into this issue today. You were right! It was the `<form>` being nested inside a `<form>`. 50 points well-earned. I thought I had tried deleting the outer `<form>`, but I must've goofed. Anyway, as a quick fix, I told them to move the start of their `<form>` with all the hidden `<input>` tags down to just above the side-nav (Some of its links call a JS function that submits the form.) That fixed it for me. From the widget, how could I do an AJAX POST cross-domain to a site I don't control? I don't think that's permitted. Must it be an iframe?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale - Check out [JSONP](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/), which means JSON with padding.  It uses script tag remoting to simulate cross-domain AJAX calls.  The only possible problem might be that it would be a GET instead of a POST, which hopefully shouldn't matter.  A quick test is to change method="post" to method="get" in a working version of your form.  If it still submits, then JSONP should do the trick.  [More info on JSONP](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/107136.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To your first problem: your page doesn't have an approriate DOCTYPE declaration, so IE refuse to render it. After I change that, IE renders the page (though still incorrectly). Hope this helps.

You can reference this link: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @Matt: about your second problem:your HTMLs are totally rendered by tons of javascript, so it's hard to debug. It will be more convenient if you could tell us which part may cause the problem.

Comment: I believe `<!DOCTYPE html>` is standard now for HTML5 and is backwards compatible. I think that link you gave is old. It has 2002 in the URL, but I'll try changing it. Thanks for the suggestion. What did you change it to?