# Advantages of Using iframe in webpages

Tags: iframe

I used a `<iframe>` in my web page and its loading takes a long time, even more than loading main web page, Any body could say what are advantages of using `<iframe>` in a webpage?

And can use another tag instead `<iframe>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3225286/650405

Comment: You could use an <img> tag, but no, seriously: What is your goal?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. It is not possible to answer to a question when it is unclear what is asked.

Answer (score 1):

Iframes are the only cross-browser way to provide html components that are truly separated. So this is their advantage.

But iframes are heavy and do not easily integrate. You may look at the emerging  [Shadow Dom](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) for an alternative.

There could be more options in your case, but you would have to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

As you said your iframe content is loading slower than your page, it is the main advantage I have came across for iframe. if you render the things on your page instead of iframe it will take the same time to load the whole page as that of iframe. Your page will be slower.

Second one is , some of the social media buttons are coming in the form of iframe like facebook like and share buttons.

Comment: I know that content of `<ifram>` load seperatley from main page, but I saw that my page elements is fully loaded except `<iframe>` content. since my page loading bar is working yet.